# Импорт pygame в проект

Tags: python, pip, модули, pygame

Возникла проблема с импортированием билиотеки pygame в проект. При просмотре списка установленных пакетов с помощью p pygame вроде установлен, но при импортировании в проект он ругается: no module named pygame.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, в проекте (в файле) есть ли в начале строка:

```
import pygame
```

Также проверьте, эта строка в самом начале, или нет.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, вполне возможно что у вас установлены 2 разные версии python, и модуль который вы установили, установился на другую версию

Answer (score 0):

Возможно он установлен некорректно.
попробуйте pip install pygame.
если он есть проверте наличие его в проекте и его правильность!

1. он в самом начале проекта.
2. нет грамот ических ошибок
   так же добавте после строки импорта строку
   pygame.init()